# How can I directly use std::get instead of a Lambda function in std::transform?

Tags: c++

I have a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of [`std::typle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/):

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> vt;
```

And I can transform the content of the vector to an other vector, by the algorithm [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/), like this:

```
std::vector<int> vi(vt.size());

std::transform( vt.begin(), vt.end(), vi.begin(), [](auto &v) -> int {
    return std::get<0>(v);
} );
```

Of course I could use a function too:

```
int myget(const std::tuple<int,int>& t)
{
    return std::get<0>(t);
}

std::vector<int> vi(vt.size());
std::transform( vt.begin(), vt.end(), vi.begin(), myget );
```

But would it be possible to use [`std::get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/get/) directly, as a actual parameter in `std::transform`?

I mean somthing like this:

```
std::transform( vt.begin(), vt.end(), vi.begin(), std::get<0, ??? > );
```

Comment: There might be some convoluted syntax to get a pointer to an instantiated instance of the `std::get` template function, and pass this pointer, as a callable object, to `std::transform`. If one is found, it would surely come with a sense of accomplishment, and a pat on one's back, for successfully navigating C++'s insanely complicated syntax. But don't labor under a myth that you've accomplished anything substantive because, in the end, it's a near certainty that the compiler will generate substantively identical code, and all you've really done is wrote an undecipherable stream of punctuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but I wouldn't recommend it *at all*. Because `std::get` has multiple overloads, you need to `static_cast` to the right one.

```
static_cast<int&(*)(std::tuple<int, int>&)>(&std::get<0, int, int>)
```

Really, that's not nice to look at, with repetition of template arguments two times. And if you want the cast to be generic, it will be pretty long.

Instead, to shorten your lambda, you can drop the `-> int`, as the return type will get automatically deduced:

```
std::transform( vt.begin(), vt.end(), vi.begin(), [](auto &v) {
    return std::get<0>(v);
} );
```

---

Someday, we might be able to write this:

```
std::transform(vt.begin(), vt.end(), vi.begin(), [](auto &v) => std::get<0>(v));
```

Comment: according to P0573R2, `std::transform(vt.begin(), vt.end(), vi.begin(), [](v) => std::get<0>(v));`

Comment: @yumetodo I guess you're right, but here's my opinionated take on it: I don't like *not* specifying the type :)

Comment: Can someone tell me what is wrong with this answer, as I'll assume that the downvote is rational? Thanks :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 You probably got the dwon vote because the question is duplicate (closed)